# Cannot download using wget (wget retry "unlimitedly")

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I've to crawl website http://docbao.com.vn/ using wget, but wget always message

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

For example, I crawled all webpages in a category http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec , then the result was

```
congnh@congnh-pc:~/Source/datasection/congnh-crawler/sh$ wget "http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec" -O -
--2013-02-20 23:53:16--  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Resolving docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)... 123.30.51.174
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:17--  (try: 2)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:19--  (try: 3)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:22--  (try: 4)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:27--  (try: 5)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:32--  (try: 6)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:38--  (try: 7)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:45--  (try: 8)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2013-02-20 23:53:53--  (try: 9)  http://docbao.com.vn/chuyenmuc/muc-1/Quoc_te.dec
Connecting to docbao.com.vn (docbao.com.vn)|123.30.51.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
...
```

Why wget retry "unlimitedly"? or what's the problem?
Thanks
Cong

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stating the obvious, but: `wget` retries because it does not receive any data. It sends the HTTP header and the remote host closes the connection immediately after that. I can just guess that this non-standard behaviour is due to a misconfiguration on the server side, maybe a deliberate one.

After poking around a bit, I found out that the content *will* get served once you signal you can handle a gzip-encoded response. You can do so by adding `--header="accept-encoding: gzip"` to your `wget` command. This again is problematic for crawling with `wget`, since it cannot recurse into gzipped content. You will need to write a script to handle this situation, or use another tool which can handle such content.

On a sidenote: Please be aware that not all websites allow scraping their content. Please check their TOS before you do so.